# play MPD file of mpeg-dash on android and IOS

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, mpeg-dash

I have used ffmpeg to create a MPD file for my video, and I could play and watch it on my pc using :http://dashplayer.azurewebsites.net/

now I want to make sure it works and plays appropriately on andoid and IOS, could anyone tell me how to test this file on android and IOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want web-based playback or native apps, so I'll try to cover both:

## Android

On Android (depending on the version / browser) this should work fine.

#### Web

At least Chrome works, but also other browsers might. You will just need a web-player which supports DASH, e.g. [Shaka Player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player), [Bitmovin Player](https://bitmovin.com/html5-player/) or [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js).

#### Native apps

For native apps, you could use e.g. Google's [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

## iOS

Assuming that you are using fragmented mp4 for your DASH content:
For iOS 10+ you could just create an HLS manifest and [re-use the same segments as for DASH](https://bitmovin.com/hls-news-wwdc-2016/). For older iOS versions you will need to create MPEG-2 Transport Stream (.ts) segments plus the HLS manifest:

#### Web

For a web-based solution, there is currently no way to achieve MPEG-DASH playback on iOS as Safari on iOS [does not provide the required JavaScript API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mediasource), the [Media Source Extensions (MSE)](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/).

#### Native apps

It could technically be possible to use MPEG-DASH, but Apple doesn't allow any other streaming format than HLS for content longer than 10 minutes, as stated in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/review/guidelines/#software-requirements):

> 2.5.7 Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes must use HTTP Live Streaming and include a baseline 192 kbps HTTP Live stream.

Comment: Very helpful thank you. Just to add there's a small typo, you wrote "10 seconds" but you clearly meant "10 minutes" as indicated in your quote. I have one minute videos and the difference would affect me.

Comment: I am trying to see if the statement above is still true about streams longer than 10 minutes. I need to display a live stream in my ios (native swift) app and the API call gives me a  MPD file to work with. What is the correct way to handle playing this file?

Comment: You will need to use or write a video player that can understand MPEG-DASH manifest (MPD) files, as Apple's built-in AVPlayer doesn't. However, such players for iOS are rare. Why can't you use HLS playlists for that stream?